# django admin FilterSpec per AdminSite

Tags: django-admin

Looking at the implementation in django.contrib.admin.filterspecs.py it seems to me that FilterSpecs are managed in a global registry they are tied up with the field type.

I am curious if it is possible to have:
- different custom filters for different AdminSite instances?
- different custom filters for a field belonging to different models?
- different custom filters for a combination of the two?

For example:

I have a class Article(models.Model) which has tags(some model Tag) associated with it. The tags have been created by users visiting the site.

- In the Articles admin page, I wish to have selection on the basis of tags.
- I have an AdminSite for super users in which all tags are visible.
- I have another AdminSite for staff users in which I wish that only those tags are visible which have been created by current user.

The above example is contrived but I hope it gives the idea.

Comment: I am now focused on developing my own interface rather than trying to make admin work for me. I guess my needs were too much of a stretch for current admin site design.